Ramsey model and the steady state
Following Barro's book about the Ramsey Model, when we work with variables expressed in units per effective labor we end up with the following system of 2 differential equations
\begin{equation}
\frac{\dot{\hat{k}}(t)}{\hat{k}(t)} = \frac{f(\hat{k}(t))}{\hat{k}(t)} - \frac{\hat{c}}{\hat{k}(t)} - (x+n+\delta) \\
\frac{\dot{\hat{c}}(t)}{\hat{c}(t)} = \theta^{-1}[f'(\hat{k}(t)) -\delta -\rho-\theta x]
\end{equation}
and the transversality condition
\begin{equation}
    \lim_{t \to \infty} \left\{ \hat{k}(t) \exp\left( - \int_{0}^{\infty} [f'(\hat{k}(s)) - \delta - x - n] \, ds \right) \right\} = 0
\end{equation}
where $\hat{k}(t) \equiv \frac{K(t) }{A(t) L(t) }$, with $K(t)$ denoting physical capital, $A(t)$ denoting the stock of technology at time $t$ which evolves according to $A(t)=e^{xt}$, and $L=e^{nt}$ is the population size. Then, $\delta$ is the depreciation rate of capital, $\rho$ is the subjective discounting rate of the household, and $\theta^{-1}$ is the intertemporal elasticity of substitution.
Then, with $(\gamma_{\hat{k}})^{\ast}$ and $(\gamma_{\hat{c}})^{\ast} $ referring to the steady state growth rate of capital and consumption per effective worker, respectively, the book says that at the steady state the differential equation for consumption implies
\begin{equation}
\hat{c}=f(\hat{k})-(x+n+\delta)\hat{k}-\hat{k}(\gamma_{\hat{k}})^{\ast}
\end{equation}
Then, differentiating the last expression for time
\begin{equation}
\dot{\hat{c}}=\dot{\hat{k}}[f'(\hat{k})-(x+n+\delta) - (\gamma_{\hat{k}})^{\ast}]
\end{equation}
must hold in the steady state. Then the book claims that the expression in the square brackets is positive from the transversality condition and so $(\gamma_{\hat{k}})^{\ast}$ and $(\gamma_{\hat{c}})^{\ast}$ must have the same sign.
It is clear that to satisfy the transversality condition it must be: $f'(\hat{k}(t)) - \delta - x - n >0$. What I do not understand is how can I infer from the transversality condition that $f'(\hat{k}(t)) - \delta - x - n - (\gamma_{\hat{k}})^{\ast} >0$ and why $(\gamma_{\hat{k}})^{\ast}$ and $(\gamma_{\hat{c}})^{\ast}$ have the same sign?
